# FlxG.collide (with setTileProperties) colliding outside the tile space in flixel

Tags: actionscript-3, collision, flixel

so I have been using flixel I some recently, and I think I am getting a feel for it, but I have come across a issue.

I have a Map class, that uses the `loadMap()` function, which comes out great.

I then use `setTileProperties()` on my Water tile, that then calls a function, calls a Boolean on my player class (to say that he is in the water), which then slows him down. This still works great, except for one thing. When I pass the water tile above or to the right (about 10-16ish pixels, haven't gotten the exact number) outside the tile, it still slows the player. I am not sure if this is just the way that `FlxG.collide()` works, or if there is something I can do to fix it, or maybe if I should find another way to use the collision. All help is appreciated.

Here is the code, if you need it:

Map.as

```
   private function createMap():void {
            loadMap(new currentMap, currentTiles, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0);
            setTileProperties(4, FlxObject.NONE, PlayerInWater);                
        }
override public function update():void {
        super.update();
        FlxG.collide(Registry.player, this);

    }

    private function PlayerInWater(tile:FlxTile, player:Player):void {
        Registry.player.inWater = true;
        trace("player is in the water"); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have figured out an answer to this, for all of you who want to know.
I used the `overlapsPoint()` method to create this:

```
private function createMap():void {
        //load Map
        loadMap(new currentMap, currentTiles, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0);
        //set water tiles
        setTileProperties(4, FlxObject.NONE);
        //put all of the water tiles in an array
        waterArray = getTileCoords(4);
    }

override public function update():void {
        super.update();
        //collision with map
        FlxG.collide(Registry.player, this);
        //loops through each water tile
        for each(var waterTile:FlxPoint in waterArray) {
            //checks if the player is overlapping the water tile
            if (Registry.player.overlapsPoint(waterTile)) {
                //if so, then the player is in water
                Registry.player.inWater = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method being so simple, it kind of makes me feel stupid for getting stuck on it, but if someone finds a more efficient method, please, go ahead and comment, or make a new answer. I always appreciate feedback.